# cakephp pagination with complex query

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.5

I have a database structure given below

```
id | Title   | brand | 
---+---------+-------+
1  |product1 | Lg    |
2  |pruduct2 | Lg    |
3  |pruduct3 | Lg    |
4  |pruduct4 | Lg    |
5  |pruduct5 | Lg    |
6  |pruduct6 |samsung|
7  |pruduct7 |samsung|
8  |pruduct8 |samsung|
9  |pruduct9 |samsung|
10 |pruduct10|samsung|
11 |pruduct11| sony  |
12 |pruduct12| sony  |
13 |pruduct13| sony  |
14 |pruduct14| sony  |
15 |pruduct15| sony  |
```

We need some query by which I can mix results by brands
Output should be like

```
id | Title   | brand | 
---+---------+-------+
1  |product1 | Lg    |
6  |pruduct6 |samsung|
11 |pruduct11| sony  |
2  |pruduct2 | Lg    |
7  |pruduct7 |samsung|    
12 |pruduct12| sony  |
.... and so on
```

I have following query which can retrieve same result

```
select id, title,brand row_number() over (partition by brand_id) as 
row_num from product_test order by row_;
```

This doesn't work with MySql unfortunately
Need a solution based on cakephp find or any other apporach

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve and you haven't stated which version of CakePHP you are using.

Comment: It is pretty clear what needs to be done but he wants you to write the code for him. :) He wan's you to write the ORM code for the SQL query he provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate the query in the following way:

```
SELECT @rownum := 0, @brand := NULL;

SELECT
  id
, title
, brand
FROM (
  SELECT
    id
  , title
  , brand
  , @rownum := IF(@brand <=> brand, @rownum + 1, 1) AS row_num
  , @brand := brand AS dummy
  FROM
    product_test
  ORDER BY
    brand
  , id
  ) product_test
ORDER BY
  row_num
, brand
, id;
```